# I want to count 4 boolean from an object and return a count of how many are true

Tags: java, boolean, logic

I have a User object which has the Boolean values of workOut1, workOut2, workOut3, workOut4
I want to create a method to return a count of how many are true. 
Example

```
Workout1 = false
Workout2 = true
Workout3 = false
Workout4 = false
```

would return 1. 
Any help would be appriciated

Comment: put the variables in list, stream, filter, count

Comment: Increment a count for every variable that's true.  No need to get fancy.  ```if (workout1) count++;``` repeat 4 times changed as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for only 4 variables it would make sense to put them in an array or list. 
If there are more you **must** do it and iterate and sum over the array, or use filtering of the list.
Now for 4 variables you can use the [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html):

```
int counter = (Workout1 ? 1 : 0) + (Workout2 ? 1 : 0) + (Workout3 ? 1 : 0) + (Workout4 ? 1 : 0);
```

Not elegant though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
long numberOfTrues = Stream.of(workout1, workout2, workout3, workout4)
                .filter(w->w)
                .count();
```

Comment: should be `w.equals(true)`

Comment: it's a lambda so it does not recognise `w.equals(true)`

Comment: of course it does. it doesn't compile otherwise. btw, you can just do `w -> w`

Comment: That seems like serious overkill to me, when you just need to add a small fixed number of simple values.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in an Array and then create a new method to iterate through the array. The method will check every boolean value inside the array and check if it's true. If it's true then the int x will be incremented by 1. Once the loop is done, it will return the value of x. Hope it helps!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        Boolean[] test = new Boolean[4];

        boolean Workout1 = false;
        boolean Workout2 = true;
        boolean Workout3 = false;
        boolean Workout4 = false;

        test[0] = Workout1;
        test[1] = Workout2;
        test[2] = Workout3;
        test[3] = Workout4;


        System.out.println(check(test));


    }

    public static int check(Boolean[] array) {
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].equals(true)) {
                x++;
            }

        }
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: way too verbose for Java in 2019